# Existing spring application extension by adding camel features

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have my web application written in Spring MVC. It is quite simple app for registering some activities and generating reports after some time. Now I have it done fully in Spring. The only entry point is HTTP webapp request. I'd like to add other entry points to allow user to trigger application via JMS queue, FTP files and SOAP-based web service.
I know I can do this all using Spring own features somehow, but I wonder if it is desirable to involve Apache Camel into all that stuff? 
I think about leaving web application as it is (communicating directly with services), only add some Camel magic to spring context and expose several endpoints from Camel and then after messages processing and transformations call existing services.

I think about using Camel to be able to use some asynchronous processing and threads/scalability features. Is it the right way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to use Apache Camel. I have used it for a similar purpose. The solution is an appropriate one from a 'Separation of Concerns' point. Camel implement Enterprise Integration Patters and is a better solution for integrating various protocols and interfaces. Your application should deal with functionality only and as designed should just expose a servlet to get requests and process it.

Handling of interfaces and protocols are well structured in Camel and its easy to maintain and configure in the long run.